# How can Passportjs return authenticate result instead of redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passportjs for user authentication. In the official guide, the only shown user case is a redirection operation after authentication:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login',
                                   failureFlash: true })
);
```

However, in my application, I don't want passport to redirect immediately. Instead, I hope passport could send me back some json object indicating whether the authentication is success or not. How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send custom responses -

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        if (!user) {
            return res.send(400, 'Incorrect username');
        }

        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            res.send({'message': 'User authenticated'});
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Cool. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: It's a method defined by passport and a reference attached to req object. It will serialize the user to store in session, which can then be deserialized in all subsequent requests.